# VBA Same number in other sheet, it will delete the entire row (other sheet)

Tags: vba, excel

In `Sheet1` I have one cell `A3` (containing e.g. `52`):

[image]

```
Dim wbThis As Workbook
Dim wsThis As Worksheet
Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
Dim tmp As Integer


    Set wbThis = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsThis = wbThis.Sheets(1)
    Set wsTarget = wbThis.Sheets(2)



    For i=1 To 100      
        wsThis.Activate
        tmp = wsThis.Cells(3, i).Value
        For j=3 To 100
            wsTarget.Activate
            If Cells(j,1).Value = tmp Then
                Cells(j,1).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

But still have a problem : `tmp = wsThis.Cells(3, i).Value----> Error written : Incompatible Type`

And I tried another code but it doesn't work, the row is not deleted.

```
Sub delete_ligne()
Dim rng as Range
Dim WB as Workbook
Dim i As Integer

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Set WB = 'define your workbook here
  Set rng = WB.Sheet(2).Range("B:B").Find (What:=WB.Sheet(1).Range("A3"), _
          LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
  While not Rng is Nothing
    rng.Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
    Set rng = WB.Sheet(2).Range("B:B").Find (What:=WB.Sheet(1).Range("A3"), _
              LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
  Wend

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Is tmp really always an integer?

Comment: I have looked on internet and I think so...